# How to host the Istio multi control plane in single cluster in single region in Google cloud

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I want to host the Istio multi control plane in single cluster in single region. I want to host the Istio on GKE and want to host on single region. The multi control plane is replicated control plane.

Answer (score 0):

This [document](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multiple-controlplanes/) provides the process of installing multiple Istio control planes within a single cluster and then a way to scope workloads to specific control planes. This deployment model has a single Kubernetes control plane with multiple Istio control planes and meshes. The separation between the meshes is provided by Kubernetes namespaces and RBAC. To host the multi control planes in a single cluster, the cluster supported versions are  1.25, 1.26, 1.27, 1.28, 1.29. This cluster will host two control planes installed in two different system namespaces.

[image]

Deploying multiple Istio control planes on a single cluster can be achieved by using different system namespaces for each control plane. **Istio revisions** and **discoverySelectors** are then used to scope the resources and workloads that are managed by each control plane. For deploying multiple control planes, you can follow this [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multiple-controlplanes/#deploying-multiple-control-planes).